# While loop doesn't work. Includes strings and converting to upper case

Tags: ruby, string, user-input

I couldn't figure out the problem with this code:

```
select = false
while (!select)
  print "What animal do you want to adopt? (Cat/Dog/Fish): "
  your_animal = gets
  if your_animal.upcase == "CAT" or your_animal.upcase == "DOG" or your_animal.upcase == "FISH"
    puts "Ah, you want #{your_animal}."
    select = true
  else
    puts "Please pick from any of the three animals and make sure it is spelled correctly."
  end
end
```

The `if` statement with the three conditions doesn't work, and will execute the code in the `else` statement even if I write the correct response for the `if` statement to be activate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
your_animal = gets
```

to

```
your_animal = gets.chomp
```

The reason is that `gets` returns the whole string input, *including the terminating carriage return*.

*Sidenote*: instead of

```
your_animal.upcase == "CAT" or 
  your_animal.upcase == "DOG" or
  your_animal.upcase == "FISH"
```

one might use:

```
%w(CAT DOG FISH).include? your_animal.upcase
```

Comment: ...and `until(select)` rather than `while(!select)`. Also, if you intend to convert the result of `gets` to an integer (not here), you can write either `gets.chomp.to_i` or just `gets.to_i`, as `.to_i` terminates the conversion as soon as it hits a character other than a digit (or the end of the string). Same with `to_f`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I read in to it after you mentioned this and I understand why; because when you put an input, the string that it gets is, for example:

"CAT
"

Which isn't the same as "CAT".

Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: Alex, no, `gets` returns `"CAT\n"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right -- this is my first time asking a question here and I didn't realize that comments posted here get rid of the empty lines. But yes, gets itself creates a new line.